# Converting the output of MediaWiki to plain text

Tags: json, bash, raspberry-pi

Using the MediaWiki API, [this](https://simple.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Tiger&format=json&exintro=1) gives me an output like so, for search term Tiger

```
https://simple.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Tiger&format=json&exintro=1
```

Response:

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"9796":{"pageid":9796,"ns":0,"title":"Tiger","extract":"<p>The <b>tiger</b> (<i>Panthera tigris</i>) is a carnivorous mammal. It is the largest living member of the cat family, the Felidae. It lives in Asia, mainly India, Bhutan, China and Siberia.</p>\n<p></p>"}}}}
```

How do I get an output as

> The tiger (Panthera tigris) is a carnivorous mammal. It is the largest living member of the cat family, the Felidae. It lives in Asia, mainly India, Bhutan, China and Siberia.

Please can someone also tell me how to store everything in a text file? I'm a beginner here so please be nice. I need this for a project I'm doing in Bash, on a Raspberry Pi 2, with Raspbian

Comment: Bash @BradSullivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually recommended to use JSON parser for handling JSON, one that I like is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
% jq -r '.query.pages[].extract' file
<p>The <b>tiger</b> (<i>Panthera tigris</i>) is a carnivorous mammal. It is the largest living member of the cat family, the Felidae. It lives in Asia, mainly India, Bhutan, China and Siberia.</p>
<p></p>
```

To remove the HTML tags you can do something like:

```
... | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Which will remove HTML tags that are not on continues lines:

```
% jq -r '.query.pages[].extract' file | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
The tiger (Panthera tigris) is a carnivorous mammal. It is the largest living member of the cat family, the Felidae. It lives in Asia, mainly India, Bhutan, China and Siberia.
```

`file` is the file the JSON is stored in, eg:

```
curl -so - 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Tiger&format=json&exintro=1' > file
jq '...' file
```

or

```
jq '...' <(curl -so - 'https://simple.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Tiger&format=json&exintro=1')
```

You can install `jq` with:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

---

For your example input you can also use `grep` with `-P` (PCRE). But using a proper JSON parser as above is recommended

```
grep -oP '(?<=extract":").*?(?=(?<!\\)")' file 
<p>The <b>tiger</b> (<i>Panthera tigris</i>) is a carnivorous mammal. It is the largest living member of the cat family, the Felidae. It lives in Asia, mainly India, Bhutan, China and Siberia.</p>\n<p></p>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? I installed jq. Now do I put your code in a bash script?

Comment: @SouvikSaha You should properly add a new question for that so this thread doesn't get to flooded :-)

Comment: Never mind I got it working :) Had to replace "$search" with '$search'. But could you tell me why single quotes are needed here?

Comment: @SouvikSaha You end single quotes, Read http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP, you can do it fairly easily such as below.

### Accessing the text

We know that the text is stored inside the `extract` property, so we need to access that.

The easiest way to do this would be to parse the string from the API into an object format, which is done with the `json_decode` method in PHP. You can then access the `extract` property from that object, and this will give you your string. The code would be something like this:

```
//Get the string from the API, however you've already done it
$JSONString = getFromAPI();

//Use the inbuilt method to create a JSON object
$JSONObject = json_decode($JSONString);

//Follow the structure to get the pages property
$Pages = JSONObject->query->pages;

//Here, we don't know what the Page ID is (because the MediaWiki API returns a different number, depending on the page)
//Therefore we need to simply get the first key, and within it should be our desired 'extract' key
$Extract = "";
foreach($Pages as $value) {
    $Extract = $value->extract;
    break;
}

//$Extract now contains our desired text
```

### Writing it to a file

Now we need to write the contents of `$Extract` to a file, as you mentioned. This can be done as follows, by utilizing the `file_put_contents` method.

```
//Can be anything you want
$file = 'APIResult.txt';

// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $Extract, LOCK_EX);
```

Aaand we're done!

***Documentation***
The documentation for these functions (`json_decode` and `file_put_contents`) can be found at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: My mistake. I didn't see the update before I finished writing the answer - apologies.

Comment: It's all right. I should've mentioned it earlier. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You may find pandoc helpful, from http://pandoc.org/ - it understands a number of file formats on input including Mediawiki, and also has a bunch of file formats on output including plain text.  It's more the "Swiss army knife" approach, and since Mediawiki is arbitrarily complicated to parse, you'll want to use something like this that's been through a big test suite.

Comment: This looks interesting. I'll give it a try.